# Professional Couriers Order Tracking REST API Issue

Tags: error, rest-api, api-response

We have used Professional Couriers REST API to get shipping tracking information.
But on my end, only three-time correct responses were returned after that given below error.

Please check the screenshot.
[image]

Would you happen to have any suggestions or ideas on the above issue?

Thank you.

Comment: The error message returned is clear that you have exceeded the number of tracking requests for this consignment. So you can confirm that the maximum API request limit for tracking request for your current plan is 3. They most likely have some `premium / paid service where you can send more number of requests than what's allowed now` and you can check that.

Comment: Thank haijerome
can you suggestion how to premium / paid service increase in professional Rest API.

Comment: I don't find any clear documentation about their API. It's better you can approach them.